# UITableViewCell Custom accessoryView button issue

Tags: objective-c, unicode, uibutton, xcode6, accessoryview

I am displaying a unicode character in a `UIButton` by creating custom accessory view in cell. The issue is the text looks very small in iPad. If I set some other string like "ABC" it displayed properly. How can I make unicode character appear Large ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the font size too high fixed the issue.I set the font size to 50 and I got desired result.